# SQL Server connection issue from node js application

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Getting below issue when I am trying to connect to SQL Server from Node Js application.

The SQL Server name used `DESKTOP-FCM7L54\SRINIVAS` is the correct one.

Error details:

> { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-FCM7L54SRINIVAS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND DESKTOP-FCM7L54SRINIVAS
>
> at Connection.base.ConnectionPool._poolCreate.base.Promise.tedious.once.err
>   (C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp3\SqlNodejs\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
>   at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
>   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>   at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
>   at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp3\SqlNodejs\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:699:14)
>   at C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp3\SqlNodejs\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:590:25
>   at C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp3\SqlNodejs\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:68:18
>   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
>   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:89:17)
>   Code: 'ESOCKET',

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
var config = {
    server: 'DESKTOP-FCM7L54\SRINIVAS', 
    database: 'Test',
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'test',
    port: 1433
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     //connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from Customer', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
    sql.close();
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error code you are getting is `ENOTFOUND`, which means the connection is not found. Verify your host and port, and that the service is indeed running on this port.
One more think you can see in your error - it says `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND DESKTOP-FCM7L54SRINIVAS` - notice the missing backslash in your name, might be escaping it. Maybe try connecting to `DESKTOP-FCM7L54\\SRINIVAS`

Another thing I'm seeing in your code, not related to this problem - you are not handling the errors correctly - you print them to the console, but not stopping the flow of your code, which can cause some undesired behavior.